# Load balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign

I'm trying to use Feign client. Below is my feing client:

```
import com.eprogrammerz.examples.domain.Movie;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Created by Yogen on 12/26/2016.
 */
@FeignClient(name = "movie-api")
public interface MovieApi {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/movies/{id}")
    Movie getMovie(@PathVariable("id") Long id);
}
```

I'm calling it from simple service as below:

```
@Service
public class MovieService {

    @Autowired
    MovieApi movieApi;

    public Movie findMovie(Long id){
        Movie movieOfTheDay = movieApi.getMovie(id);
        return movieOfTheDay;
    }
}
```

My spring boot app is as below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.EnableCircuitBreaker;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;

@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.eprogrammerz.examples"})
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'client-app'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-core
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"){
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}
```

I'm getting error as below:

```
2016-12-30 13:07:16.894  INFO 6748 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 39 ms
2016-12-30 13:07:16.939  INFO 6748 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] c.e.e.controllers.RequestController      : Calling findMovie(1203)
2016-12-30 13:07:17.240  INFO 6748 --- [rix-movie-api-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@547496c2: startup date [Fri Dec 30 13:07:17 EST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@542e560f
2016-12-30 13:07:17.318  INFO 6748 --- [rix-movie-api-1] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-12-30 13:07:17.619  INFO 6748 --- [rix-movie-api-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: movie-api.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2016-12-30 13:07:17.670  INFO 6748 --- [rix-movie-api-1] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-movie-api
2016-12-30 13:07:17.727  INFO 6748 --- [rix-movie-api-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client:movie-api instantiated a LoadBalancer:DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=movie-api,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2016-12-30 13:07:17.739  INFO 6748 --- [rix-movie-api-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2016-12-30 13:07:17.746  INFO 6748 --- [rix-movie-api-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client movie-api initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=movie-api,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@45bcfd5
2016-12-30 13:07:18.191 ERROR 6748 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: MovieApi#getMovie(Long) failed and no fallback available.] with root cause

com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: movie-api
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:468) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97) ~[feign-core-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76) ~[feign-core-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108) ~[feign-hystrix-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:301) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:297) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
```

I tried different way. But couldn't figure out the solution. I couldn't find any information about this on [Spring Cloud Netflix](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#spring-cloud-feign) too. I couldn't find any information on [discussion thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500174/spring-cloud-service-look-up-error-load-balancer-does-not-have-available-server) too.

What I'm missing here? TIA.

Further Details:

application.yml for movie-api microservice is as below:

```
server:
  port: 8090
logging:
  config: classpath:log4j2.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: movie-api
```

Spring boot app on movie-api module:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MovieApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And controller is as below:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class MovieController {
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/movies/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> getBook(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        log.trace("getBook({})",id);
        Optional<Movie> movie = Optional.of(movieRepository.findOneById(id));
        if(movie.isPresent())
            return new ResponseEntity(movie.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a service discovery such as Eureka or Consul? If so, have you defined the configuration in your Spring Boot app's application.yml to register the app as a client to Eureka? Basically, Feign is complaining that it could not find the service registered anywhere. You can very easily configure a service discovery like Eureka using Spring Cloud. See http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/

Comment: @Bloodysock so on which side should i use discovery service? Here on client side or api side?

Comment: You'd register your API (better term would be "service") with a unique name to the service discovery. The client simply discovers the service and invokes it. Spring Cloud makes it real easy for the developer especially with Spring Boot. Go through the example documented at the site I linked above. You will on your way making the service calls in 15 minutes :)

Comment: @Bloodysock yes you are right! i was missing 'service' registration. Thank you!.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After doing research, and with help of @Bloodysock, I found that I was missing registration of remote server in 'client-app' micro-service. The document is at [Spring Cloud Netflix](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html).

I used Ribbon without Eureka with configuration in `application.yml` in '`client-app`' micro-service as:

```
movie-api:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: http://localhost:8090
```

Comment: how do you set it up so as to not have to hardcode movie-api 's url but letting ribbon use eureka to find out the urls of movie-api ??

Comment: @xpz as far as i know, we should do server side load balancing to achieve that!

Comment: @xpz please check https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1754436 with more details

Answer (score 25):

The problem is that your service doesn't know the host of requested service. If you are using Eureka, put this line on your .properties file:

`eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true`

OR .yml file:

```
eureka:
    client:
        fetch-registry: true
```

It'll make your service talk with Eureka and discover the host of the requested service.

Answer (score 7):

If your Spring Cloud set up **does not support specifying the servers in application.properties**/application.yml, you have to configure the services URL in a Configuration class.

Pls, note the ***warning message*** in my application.properties [Spring Boot v2.0.0RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-feign & spring-cloud-starter-ribbon v 1.4.3.RELEASE]

[image]

So what I did was to write a Configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
class LocalRibbonClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList() {
        // return new ConfigurationBasedServerList();
        StaticServerList<Server> staticServerList = new StaticServerList<>((new Server("localhost", 8001)),
                new Server("localhost", 8000));
        return staticServerList;
    }
}
```

Then, configured the Spring Boot Application to use this configuration as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients("my-package.currencyconversionservice")
@RibbonClient(name = "currency-conversion-service", configuration = LocalRibbonClientConfiguration.class)
public class CurrencyConversionServiceApplication {
 // nothing new here...
}
```

No need to change the Feign Proxy class. Posting just for this post to be served as a complete solution to the problem:

```
@FeignClient(name="currency-exchange-service")
@RibbonClient(name="currency-exchange-service")
public interface CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy {
    @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
    public CurrencyConversionBean retrieveExchangeValue(@PathVariable("from") String from, @PathVariable("to") String to);
}
```

That's all. The problem was fixed.

Answer (score 7):

I nearly wasted 2 hours to find the root cause. I mistakenly imported EnableEurekaClient in client application, which was the root cause for the issue. I finally resolved this issue by removing the import. To my surprise @EnableDiscoveryClient does not require the below dependency. 
But if you are using Eureka Naming server than this has to be used.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks It resolved same problem here with using your solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the application.properties file of your Zuul Gateway add this line.

movie-api.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:8080

In general -
***{{name-of-the-service}}.ribbon.listOfServers={{url-of-the-service}}***

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your service doesn't know the host of the requested service. If you are using Eureka and zuul, put this line on your zuul .properties or .yml file :

eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that `ClientAppApplication` doesn't know your eureka server's address.
You could check you applation.yml

```
eureka
  instance:
    hostname: cloud-feignorder-consume
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false #default true     
    fetch-registry: true #default true
```

The last line you should check the property 'eureka.client.fetch-registry'.It should be true or not sign.Then your client could get the server list from eureka server.

Answer (score 0):

Without eureka, in client app, if you dont have application.yml rather application.properties file, then you can set the property as below before the client app restart :

currency-exchange-service.ribbon.listOfServers : http://localhost:8000,http://localhost:8001

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this error and I would like to add my contribution to this question because it's the first one Google returns. Hope it helps.

My project uses Spring Boot `2.3.4.REALEASE` and Eureka Client `3.1.3`.
What solved my case was switching Eureka Client to version `2.1.6.RELEASE`.

I believe that for some reason the newest version was breaking Spring older version.

You guys can check my project at this point if you want:
https://github.com/mahonrimaia/course-microservices/tree/08e1db607729d37752bac5c68cd98c4a7dbfe20d

Answer (score 0):

Using Feign client I was facing this error, but the request was still failing.  The main reason was that I had not specified url attribute and only specified the value attribute.

Before correction

```
@FeignClient(value = "${url-value-in properties-files}", configuration = FeignConfiguration.class)
```

After Correction

```
@FeignClient(name = "class-name", url = "${url-value-in properties-files}", configuration = FeignConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add Ribbon along with Eureka Client, otherwise the service won't be fetched.

in my pom.xml I have:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in my service proxy:

```
@FeignClient(name = "movie-api")
@RibbonClient(name = "movie-api")
public interface MovieApi {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/movies/{id}")
    Movie getMovie(@PathVariable("id") Long id);
}
```

Comment: share your project with github or gitlab so I can check it and make a PR