# FeignClient not working with service name when using Consul for Service Discovery

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign

I am using Consul for service discovery and both my services are registered with Consul as it is visible in Consul UI.

[Consul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCxyf.png)
But when I am trying to use Feign Client from my example service to access an open endpoint available in auth-service I am getting

> "com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have
>   available server for client: auth-service".

**Auth-Service**
*AuthServiceApplication.java*

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.learning.*"})
public class AuthServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

*bootstrap.yaml*

```
spring:
  application:
    name: auth-service
```

**Example-Service**
*ExampleService.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients(
    basePackages = {"com.learning.feign.*"}
)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.learning.*"})
public class ExampleService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleService.class, args);
    }
}
```

*AuthFeignClient.java*

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "auth-service"
)
public interface AuthFeignClient {
    @GetMapping({"/testData"})
    ResponseEntity<GetPublicKeyResponse> getTestData();
}
```

**Note:** Feign is working fine when I am hardcoding the URL which I don't want to.
When I am trying to consume the auth-service end point I am not able to.

[image]

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401009/load-balancer-does-not-have-available-server-for-client

Comment: Yes, I do. But my requirement is a bit different. I don't want to maintain the list of servers in properties file. I want to use the DiscoveryClient to get the instances from Consul and Feign can use the same to communicate.

Comment: Hi, how do you declare your consul server/cluster for discovery (spring.cloud.consul) ? And is your "auth-service" well registered in it ?