# Why can't the load balancer find needed microservice using eureka?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

[image: Project structure]

The clientui serves webpages, using data from the 3 microservices.

I succesfully setted up ribbon to load balance between 2 instances of "microservice-produits". It works when i have this line `microservice-produits.ribbon.listOfServers=localhost:9001,localhost:9011` in application.properties of clientui.

**Now i'd like to make it work without having to hardcode the microservices url.**

This is what i've tried :

[image: Content of application.properties (clientui)]

with application class :

[image: Main of clientui]

and RibbonClient interface : 
[image]

and pom (clientui) :

[image]

Following these answers ([Load balancer does not have available server for client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401009/load-balancer-does-not-have-available-server-for-client)): 
[image]

I tried adding the fetchRegistry line inside application.properties and adding / removing netflix-eureka-client and netflix-eureka-server dependencies inside (clientui) pom.xml

**No matter what i always get this** : 
[image]

For info, the eureka console : 
[image]

**So : any idea ??**

Comment: Client ui should have eureka client starter no server

Comment: yes, i tried both

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and not

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

solved my problem.